# PHP: Tinymce "styling" not saving changes

Tags: php, sql, tinymce

I am having a problem with Tinymce which has only started occuring recently. I have a PHP page with Tinymce on it. When I click the submit button to save the changes to TinyMCE, it does NOT save the styling - font size, bold, images etc, but only saves the text. It inserts it into my SQL database.

I feel it is something to do with the p tag, because before the problem occured, all submitted pieces of text were wrapped inside p tags, whereas they aren't now.

I have no idea what is wrong though! The text is not inserting using something like filter(), so no PHP strings are making the errors.

Tinymce header:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        mode : "exact",
        plugins : "emotions,spellchecker,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,justifyleft, justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,separator,fontsizeselect,fontselect,styleselect,forecolor,backcolor,image, separator,blockquote,link,emotions,spellchecker,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "fullpage",
        editor_selector :"mceEditor",
        elements : "tinyMCE",


    skin : "o2k7",
    skin_variant : "silver",

});
</script>
```

The textbox with Tinymce attached to it:

```
<td><textarea name="signature" align="left" style="width:760px;height:50px;" id="tinyMCE"><?php echo $lolassoc['signature']; ?></textarea></td>
```

The PHP query which inserts into the database (the post['signature'] part uses tinymce.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET block_newfriends='$_POST[block_newfriends]', details='".clean($_POST['details'])."', accept_trading='clean($_POST[accept_trading])', hide_online='clean($_POST[hide_online])', signature='".$_POST['signature']."' WHERE id = '" . USER_ID . "'");
header("Location: ".WWW."/identity/settings");
```

If you need more clarification, please let me know. Thanks! :)

Comment: Also I must add, before this error started occuring, all HTML would display correct on the page, whereas it only shows as text now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long while, I have found the issue. It was nothing to do with TinyMCE, it was a wierd script in one of my configuration files! Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET block_newfriends='$_POST[block_newfriends]', details='".clean($_POST['details'])."', accept_trading='clean($_POST[accept_trading])', hide_online='clean($_POST[hide_online])', signature='".$_POST['signature']."' WHERE id = '" . USER_ID . "'");
```

to

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET block_newfriends='$_POST[block_newfriends]', details='".clean($_POST['details'])."', accept_trading='".clean($_POST[accept_trading])."', hide_online='".clean($_POST[hide_online])."', signature='".$_POST['signature']."' WHERE id = '" . USER_ID . "'");
```

Please go through documentation 
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_children

Comment: Not the problem. I changed it, but still when I edit my 'signature', it adds it into the database, but takes out the styling like p, font, span, img tags. I do now know why it is doing that.

Comment: what is the post request to server for signature, can you post a screen shot with firebug

Comment: Its posting the text into the textbox. The textbox has tinymce "attached to it" so that you can easily edit the styles and add images etc. It works all fine, but when I click "submit", it for some reason deletes all the style tags, and only uploads the actual text to the database (SQL).

Comment: <BR><input type="submit" value="Update Profile Settings" name="SET_NEW_VALUES_2" id="buttonsetting" /></td>

   Thats the Submit button if that somehow helps.

Comment: add valid_children : "+body[style]" in tinyMCE.init object

Comment: Still happening. http://pastebin.com/hTr99wAK for the full file. The tinyMCE code is in another file but is linked to this file.

Comment: It basically just deleted all of the styling from the text once it is inserted into the database. I do not know why though, because I am not "filtering" the text at all. This has only just started occuring recently, and I have not touched the code.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/a054e3fe8df156dd93670e9279d9d2d0

    Image of what is happening. The first row is when I try inserting it, and the rows below it work correctly, and the style inserted without disappearing, unlike mine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17090/discussion-between-saquib-and-zuc0001)

Comment: <p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://i1256.photobucket.com/albums/ii495/animeboy333/Sig.png" alt="Keith WIlson" width="510" height="100" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><em><strong><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva; font-size: small;"><span style="color: #00ffff;">Custom</span> <span style="color: #00ff00;">Furni</span> <span style="color: #ff00ff;">Maker</span></span></strong></em></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>

     Should look something like that when inserted. But it only inserts the text, none of the tags.